# Puzzled about output of "typeof" in R

Tags: r, type-conversion, typeof

I cannot understand this output. I'm posting some dummy code because the real data is of course very large, but if you think it's necessary I could post it.

```
Field <- "COUNTRIES"
M <- a.dataframe.with.country.info

typeof(M[, Field])
#[1] "list"
typeof(M[, "COUNTRIES"])
#[1] "list"
typeof(M$COUNTRIES)
#[1] "character`
```

The function I need to use will use `M[, Field]` as input, and I need it to be a character, not a list.

I'm clueless.

Thanks in advance :D

I tried converting using `unlist` and `as.character`, but none of this worked. The last resource is to expose the (third-party) function and change the line which is causing the error `Error in strsplit(M[, Field], sep) : non-character argument`

Comment: The `typeof` function really isn't that insightful. What you want to look at is `class()`. What is `class(M)`? I'm guessing it might be a `tbl`?

Comment: A dataframe is a list of columns. `M[, "COUNTRIES"]` is still a dataframe, with just one column. `$` extracts the column, so the result is not a list anymore, but a vector of the type `character`

Comment: @HaukeL. That's not true. If you subset a data.frame down to a single column, it automatically becomes a vector because the default is `drop=TRUE`. You need to use `M[, "COUNTRIES", drop=FALSE]` to keep it a data.frame. The behavior is different for tibbles which is what packages like `dplyr` use instead of regular data.frames. Try with `M <- data.frame(A=1); class(M[, "A"])` and compare that to `M <- tibble::tibble(A=1); class(M[, "A"])`

Comment: @MrFlick. Thanks for the hint. I was indeed comparing `typeof(diamonds[["cut"]])` with `typeof(diamonds[, "cut"])` and generalised that to dataframes, which isn't correct

Comment: @MrFlick, the output is 
class(collab.data[, Field]) # 1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(collab.data[, "AU_CO"]) # 1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
class(collab.data$AU_CO) # [1] "character

Comment: @GabrielaPerry As suspected that means you don't actually have a data.frame, you have a tibble. The subsetting rules are different between them. If you have tibble you are probably using `dplyr` so using `dplyr::pull(M, Field)` would work for both types of data.objects.

Comment: using `M[[Field]]` should also get you what you want.  What would have been good to post in the first place would be `summary(you_real_data_frame)`, which would tell us *about* your data set without needing to see the whole thing ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your replies, I can see now what was going on. I did not realize that tibbles are not the same as dataframes. So indeed "pull" (as suggested by @MrFlick) and casting to "dataframe" did the job.
I cannot change the `M[, Field]` line, because it is a third-party code - but it was the source of the error in the strsplit method.